Problems using ubuntu22 acpi
I installed dual systems and used ubuntu22. After the installation was successful, Bluetooth and wifi could not be found. The following is the log, and acpi reported an error. how can i solve
[    0.393571] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.393571] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.393571] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.393571] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.413488] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230331/dsfield-637)
[    0.413500] fbcon: Taking over console
[    0.413506] ACPI Warning: NsLookup: Type mismatch on SMIB (Integer), searching for (RegionField) (20230331/nsaccess-696)
[    0.417745] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dswload2-162)
[    0.417758] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230331/psobject-220)
[    0.417766] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.421119] ACPI: 12 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.424323] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.428762] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.428763] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.432676] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.432679] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.432682] ACPI: Interpreter enabled

